# Why didn't I get the bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

[sum of count(*) for all rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557593/sum-of-count-for-all-rows-in-mysql/56557672#56557672)

This question's bounty already ended but the bounty wasn't assigned to me even though my answer was accepted.

Answer (score 10):

The bounty was started on [Jun 21 at 5:35](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56557593/timeline). Your answer was added on [Jun 12 at 8:23](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56557672/timeline) i.e. before the bounty started.

Per the [bounty rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted).

Since your answer was written before the bounty started you could only receive it manually. The OP didn't award the bounty manually so one of the answers that did qualify for automatic awarding received half of it.